# Side effects of * { backface-visibility: hidden; }?

Tags: css

I'm trying to improve animation speeds in chrome and adding

```
  *,
  *::after,
  *::before {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Seems to have amazing effect. I don't have any animations running like 3d rotation where one side is shown and than the other so don't really need this, but as a precaution wanted to check if setting backface like this globally has any sort of side effects besides noticeable increase in performance?

EDIT: this fixed some flickering issues in safari as well

Comment: Heh, given how buggy backface-visibility: hidden is in Chrome, I'm surprised anyone would even consider doing something like this.

Comment: @BoltClock hmmm, I haven't noticed any changes besides perf boost on keyframe animations and transitions from this. Tried in current LTS and canary, both work fine, wonder if earlier versions have issues

Comment: Just noticed you mentioned that you're not using any 3D animations, so that may be why.